# Make span to side stay with jquery none display

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following code in html:

```
<input type="text" name="teste" id="teste" required>
<span class="corpoSpanClasse_Teste">
     Mensagem
</span>
```

I need that when someone inserts something in the input then the immediately next span stays with display none.

So far I have been able to do this code, but I do not know how to proceed.

```
$("input").on("input",function () {

})
```

I need this in jquery.

However, I have several "input" and for each "input" I have a "span" then with the message. For each change of content of the input the message contained in the span must disappear.

Example:

```
<input type="text" name="teste" id="teste" required>
<span class="corpoSpanClasse_Teste">
     Mensagem
</span>

<input type="text" name="teste1" id="teste1" required>
<span class="corpoSpanClasse_Teste1">
     Mensagem
</span>

<input type="text" name="teste2" id="teste2" required>
<span class="corpoSpanClasse_Teste2">
     Mensagem
</span>
```

Comment: you want the span text to display whatever a user puts into input? Or you want to hide the span element on user input?

Comment: No. I want the span to have the display equal to none. That is, the message you present should disappear. I am displaying an error message in this span because the user typed something they should not type. Thus, when it changes the content of the input this message no longer needs to appear by the hour.

Comment: What if they then delete all the input text?

Comment: Why not use a placeholder?

Comment: It's a good idea I had not thought of that. But for now I will try to do this other way for learning as well. Thanks for the personal support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `change` or `keyup` to solve this, [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26941893/differences-between-keyup-event-and-change-event-in-username-live-change) some good explanation on its difference

`change`:

```
$('#teste').change(function() {
    $('.corpoSpanClasse_Teste').hide();
});
```

`keyup`:

```
$('#teste').on('keyup', function() {
    $('.corpoSpanClasse_Teste').hide();
});
```

I also changed your input filter `$("input")` for `$('#teste')` to be specific to this one input and don't trigger all input's on the page

Comment: The problem is that I have several inputs on the screen that can display a message and this message should be deleted when someone changes the input. The span containing the message is immediately next to the input.

Comment: @RenanAngeliniFerrari so you can have one span next to one input? You should've mentioned that and provided code sample because it will change the solution

Comment: Do not worry if I mispronounced. But all the inputs I have, immediately below them there is a "span". This "span" contains an error message if the user enters something wrong. I need this "span" to disappear after the user changes the input because the alert has already been given. Thanks for your help and I hope that now I have understood the problem. I'm sorry again for anything.

Comment: @RenanAngeliniFerrari you can just modify your question and I'll help you with the answer, pretty sure I know what you talking about

Comment: I changed the question. However, I have already been able to perform the procedure with the following code:     $("input").on("input",function () {
        $(this).next().css("display","none");
    });  
Now I'm going to change with the change or keyup events you mentioned. Thank you very much for your help and apologize again for the inconvenience.

Comment: @RenanAngeliniFerrari yes thats the way to do it, glad you were able to solve this