# Enter information in input and shows the information on the div's textContent simultaneously

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm a HTML JS beginner.
Right now I'm doing a Meme generator project and I encounter a problem

this is my HTML code

```
//this is input tag

<div>
<input type="text" placeholder = 'text' class="mtext">
<input type="text" placeholder = 'text' class="mtext">
</div>

//this is my div block.

<div id = "meme">
     <div class="mtext1" style = 'left: 5px; top: 5px; width: 400px; height: 25px'></div>
     <div class="mtext1" style = 'left: 5px; top: 5px; width: 400px; height: 25px'></div>
</div>
```

and my thought is wanting to use "addEventListener" to solve this problem.

```
const  inputText = document.querySelectorAll('.mtext')
const showTextBox = document.querySelectorAll('.mtext1')


inputText.addEventListener('????' , function(){
  showtextbox.textContent += 

})
```

the first problem is what addEventListener parameter is proper to meet my expectation? That I can type into the text box and shows the result on div box at the same time.

the second problem is my inputText and showTextBox are array-like value, how can I extract the value for each of inputText and represent to the right showTextBox?

Thank you

Comment: Are you looking for `keyup` event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are looking for the `change` event. [Check this website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event)

```
// this code is wrong, read below.
inputText.addEventListener('change' , function(){
  // code
});
```

second, `inputText` and `showTextBox` are not what you think they are.

`document.querySelectorAll` gives you a NodeList which is just a list of html elements (for example - [elem1, elem2...] ). See [this website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). So `inputText` and `showTextBox` are lists.

You need to put an `eventListener` to every one of those elements in the list:

```
inputText.forEach(element => {
  // add eventListener to every element in the list:
  element.addEventListener('change', function () {
    // element.value gives the value inside your input elements.
    // your code
  })
});
```

The code above puts `change` eventListener to every `mtext` class.

Here is how you do it:

```
const inputText = document.querySelectorAll('.mtext');
const showTextBox = document.querySelectorAll('.mtext1');

//element is current element, index is the current element's index
inputText.forEach((element, index) => {
  // add eventListener to every element in the list:
  element.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    // element.value gives the value inside your input elements.
        showTextBox[index].innerText = element.value        
  })
});
```

Here is the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/uzbeki/jcs1hpqg/)

you can also use `keyup`, but as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26941920/13839129) discusses:

> The reason you should not use keyup() is because if a user inputs a value using autofill, it will not fire the keyup() event. However, autofill does fire the change() event, and your verification script will run, and the input will be verified.

Comment: I did not fully get your question. To change the `mtext1` text again:
    create a `changeText()` function that updates the `mtext1` values every time there is a 
    `change` event.