# how to use auto response for <select><option> to search via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i'm trying to make an auto search via ajax , but the input is inside `select` `option` tags

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var searchForm = $('.search-form')
    var searchInput = searchForm.find("[name='invoice_no']")
    var typingTimer;
    var typingInterval = 100
    searchInput.keyup(function(e){
      console.log(searchInput.val())
    })
  })
```

```html
    <form method="GET" class="search-form">
        <div>
            <div class="w-full px-2 md:w-3/12 mt-5 whiteBG py-1 mx-auto rounded-lg">
                <select name="invoice_no"  class="selectpicker text-black text-center" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true" class='text-center'>
                    <option value="" selected='true' disabled='true' class='text-center'>search</option>
                    
                    <option  value="one" class='text-center'>one</option>
                    <option  value="two" class='text-center'>two</option>
                              
                </select>      
                <button><i class="fas fa-search text-lg grayCOLOR ml-5"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

but shows nothing ! is there something i should change please ?

Comment: `change` instead of  `keyup` ?

Comment: Hi, is it selectpicker ?

Comment: @Swati yes it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Differences between keyup() event and change() event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26941893/differences-between-keyup-event-and-change-event-in-username-live-change/26941920#:%7E:text=The%20reason%20you%20should%20not,when%20the%20element%20loses%20focus.)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var searchForm = $('.search-form')
    var searchInput = searchForm.find("[name='invoice_no']")
    // var typingTimer;
    // var typingInterval = 100
    searchInput.change(function(e){
      console.log(searchInput.val())
    })
  })
```